# Python append to global variable within for loop

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm writing a python GTK+ application that has a list. I would like to be able to add items to the list from an outside class.

I create a list

```
list = [("", "No content yet!")]
```

Inside of the class, in the **init**, I create a ListStore(str, str) as a global variable, so I can append to it from add_item() method, like so:

```
def __init__(Gtk.Window):
    ...
    global list_store
    list_store = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)
    self.pop_list()
    ...

def add_item(self, item):
    list.append(item)
    pop_list()
```

I also have a method called pop_list which re-populates the liststore:

```
def pop_list(self):
    for item in list:
        item_list_store.append(item)
```

When I run the application, i get an error saying item_list_store is not defined in pop_list. I'm sure this is not the correct way to do this, but I'm pretty new to Python so I'd appreciate some assistance. Thanks!

Comment: Make it an *attribute*, not a global variable.

Comment: Also, should `item_list_store.append(item)` be `list_store.append(item)`, since `list_store` is defined, but `item_list_store` does not appear to be mentioned anywhere else in the code?

Comment: Yea, copy/paste error @Simon

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that did it, thanks bud